# ForeignKeys and historical data

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have a Quote table that generates a price based on lots of parameters. Price is generated based on data from multiple other tables like: Charges, Coupon, Promotions etc. The best way to deal with it is using ForeignKeys. Here's the table (all _id fields are foreign keys):

```
Quote
#user input fields
charge_id
promotion_id
coupon_id
tariff_id
```

Everything looks good. Each quote record has very detailed data that tells you where the price comes from. The problem is the data in the tables that it depends on isn't guaranteed to stay the same. It might get deleted or get changed. Let's say a Quote has a foreign key to a tariff and then it gets changed. The records associated with it no longer tell the same story. How do you deal with something like this? Would really appreciate if you recommend some theory related to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your quote values to be changed by change in foreign key related objects, the best bet is to add all fields from individual foreign keys models in the Quote class.

Then while calculating the values of `Quote`, you fetch data from all the (now not) related objects and save them in the Quotes table.

Now any changes to Foreign tables will not affect the Quotes table.

Another option would be to use a library like [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/quick_start.html) and that keeps track of all changes to the models with change of time.